# SQL Query: Select the sum(quantity) and count(number) SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to query the chinnok database to select sum of quantity tracks purchase and count the number of times the track appears in a playlist in one query.
Here is what I have:

```
/* Query 3 : which artist has the most songs on the top 100 songs across playlist and the most sold 
songs*/
SELECT ar.Name Artist_Name, tr.Name Track_Name, count(pl.Name) Play_List, pt.TrackId Track_ID, 
SUM(il.Quantity) Qty,
CASE WHEN count(pl.Name)=5 THEN "Five Stars"
ELSE "Four Star" END AS Ranking
FROM Track tr
JOIN PlaylistTrack pt
ON pt.TrackId = tr.TrackId
JOIN Playlist pl
ON pl.PlaylistId=pt.PlaylistId
JOIN Album ab
ON ab.AlbumId = tr.AlbumId
JOIN Artist ar
ON ar.ArtistId = ab.ArtistId
JOIN InvoiceLine il
ON il.TrackId = tr.TrackId
GROUP BY tr.TrackId
ORDER BY Play_List DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Here is the results:
[Fist 6 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbDEZ.png)
[First 16 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCKtV.png)

The Qty is correct but the Play_list number is not.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure the Qty is correct ? I think for the top line (Scheherazade) the value is 2, not 10 (2 lines in InvoiceLine, each one with a Quantity of 1)

Comment: When I do separate query to count the number of time the song is purchase it shows 10. Tell you the truth I am not 100% certain that it is correct